# ASP.NET user sessions and locks (2 different browsers)

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, locking

I have statistics reports that is displayed the form of a chart. Multiple users can access 
the web page at a time to display a report/chart.

The issue is when a single user accesses 2 different reports from 2 different browsers (IE and Firefox).
If a report is bigger, it will take more time to generate the chart. So when user opens a big report in one browser (FF), 
while it is loading, if user opens another small report in IE, small report chart is shown quickly. 
But the big report chart has some of chart properties (chart name) of small chart when it completes loading.

The issue does not exist when one user uses 2 different instances of the same browser to open 2 charts. In this case, 
second browser instance completes generating chart only after first instance is completed.

I use a lock(obj) to lock the part of code where the chart is generated.
My question is if I use this lock, how does it affect the performance in case of multiple users accessing the page?
***More specifically, does it make other users wait until first user is finished generating chart? Or is it only for a single user using different browsers?*** Using ASP.NET Framework 4.

I read about locks, asp.net session states, threading to understand this context. But I am still not sure.
Please help.

Comment: The problem may be related to utilization of same variables (perhaps Server Variables) in different reports. When the second chart loads itself, erase or update the first chart...

Comment: @David BS Yes. The logic to generate the chart is same, so the chart name is set by a value in the statistics. Though it is set for the first big report correctly, it is later updated by the value of small report. By the time first big report load is completed, it uses the last updated value (value from small report) as chart name. Could you explain more on erasing/updating the chart at later point?

Comment: Sounds like you are not locking in the right place. If the first chart has the critical section locked, the second chart should wait for the first to release the lock before gaining access to the critical section. You must lock, not only the code that generates the chart, but any code that may update a value used in generating the chart.

Comment: Propably you are using PUBLIC variables or SERVER VARIABLES that could lead to that situation. Try to utilize SESSION VARIABLES instead SERVER VARIABLES and avoid public ones in the code-behind. But a bad configuration in the server manager (IIS ?) on how Session Variables are treated can also impact on this.  ANother problem could be some databas temporary record/field, updated by reports. Be sure each report session has its own record.

Comment: Are you using some add-in or object or library to create the reports? Or are you using your own code (hand-made)?

Comment: @Kevin The issue does not exist after using the lock(obj). I tested it the case with 2 instances of same user. My question is how does it affect when there are 2 users. User1 opens a big report, does user2 opening another small chart require to wait till user1 finishes?

Comment: @David Reports are constantly generated and stored in DB based on an ongoing process. I fetch this data and generate the chart.